# R: leave a dataset out in a loop

Tags: r, loops, time

I've got a problem doing some calculations in R: I've got a large amount of datasets A[i] and on each of those datasets I'm running some iterated calculations, until the difference between two iterations becomes small enough. However, for one particular A[j], my calculations take way too long, so I suspect that data doesn't fit my method too well and I want to leave it out. 
So my question is: can I write a condition in my while loop, such that if a certain time period is exceeded, R just disregards that dataset and goes on to the next one? So does there exist something like this:

```
while (abs (a-b) > 0.01){
    calculations
    for (j in 1:n){
          if (time > amount){results A[j] <- 0}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sys.time()` before you enter the loop, and then inside the loop check the time again to get the time the loop is running.